# Auto-Refresh Page for Google Chrome on iPad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, refresh

Is there an extension I can download on an iPad to auto-refresh a Google Chrome page?

Comment: Nope. There is not.

Comment: @JohnRamos please use comments for clarification and answer section for answers. Thanks!

Comment: Jailbroken or not?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for iPad doesn't have extensions, but you can accomplish what you're looking for (in Chrome or Safari) using a bookmarklet.

I tested [Evan Culver's](https://gist.github.com/eculver/267327/ab6bd3988cb11e1881bc889bedbfa243a130548e) and it works beautifully:

`javascript: timeout=prompt("Set timeout [s]"); current=location.href; if(timeout>0) setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout); else location.replace(current); function reload(){ setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout); fr4me='<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame src=\''+current+'\'/>'; fr4me+='</frameset>'; with(document){write(fr4me);void(close())};}`

How to install it on Chrome:

1. On your iPad, copy the above line of in its entirety (starting with `javascript`and ending with the final `}`)
2. In Chrome, create a new bookmark (of any page) by tapping the star icon in the location bar. Next, immediately tap the `Edit` button in the note that will appear at the bottom of the screen, which will let you edit the new bookmark and turn it into a bookmarklet.
3. Set the name of the bookmark to "Auto Refresh"
4. Delete the whole URL and paste the code above in its place. Tap `Done` to finish creating your bookmarklet.

To use it:

1. Visit a page you want to refresh
2. Tap the location bar and *type* "Auto Refresh". Select the bookmarklet from the drop down options
3. Choose your refresh interval (in seconds)

Note: this particular bookmarklet doesn't have an option to *stop* auto-refresh; to do that, just reload the page *manually*.